# Wait for a function to finish in golang

Tags: go, synchronization

I have the following code in golang:

```
func A(){
  go print("hello")
}

func main() {
  A()
  // here I want to wait for the print to happen
  B()
}
```

How can I somehow ensure that B() will be executed only after the print has happened?

Comment: Use sync.WaitGroup or delete 'go'

Comment: @Para the thing is I want to use it concurrently (I do more complicated stuff there, I changed it for simplicity). How can I use a WaitGroup here? even if I set it after A() has finished, the print might have not completed yet, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sync.Mutex

```
var l sync.Mutex

func A() {
    go func() {
        print("hello")
        l.Unlock()
    }()
}

func B() {
    print("world")
}

func TestLock(t *testing.T) {
    l.Lock()
    A()
    l.Lock()
    // here I want to wait for the print to happen
    B()
    l.Unlock()
}
```

Use sync.WaitGroup

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup

func A() {
    go func() {
        print("hello")
        wg.Done()
    }()
}

func B() {
    print("world")
}

func TestLock(t *testing.T) {
    wg.Add(1)
    A()
    wg.Wait()
    // here I want to wait for the print to happen
    B()
}
```

Use chan

```
func A() chan struct{} {
    c := make(chan struct{})
    go func() {     
        print("hello")
        c <- struct{}{}
    }()
    return c
}

func B() {
    print("world")
}

func TestLock(t *testing.T) {
    c := A()
    // here I want to wait for the print to happen
    <-c
    B()
}
```

Comment: I think the channel send should be after the print call

Comment: yes, you are right

Answer (score 0):

You could either

1. make A() synchronous

```golang
func A(){
  print("hello") // go keyword removed
}
```

This way you are sure that `print()` has been executed after `A` returns

2. Wait for something that only happens after the `print()` execution

With a simple channel:

```golang
func A() chan struct{}{
  c := make(chan struct{})
  go func(){
     print("hello")
     close(c)
  } 
  return c 
}

func main() {
  c := A()
  // here I want to wait for the print to happen
  <-c
  B()
}
```

You could also use a `sync.Waitgroup` or `x/sync.Errgroup`

Comment: I need it asynchronous.  As of the second code example, I think it allows the print to happen after B(), doesn't it?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to close the channel in the second example. It should be better now